# React : this.state.renderData.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I am working on a React project. I am using search filter in my project but in meantime when User type something in search box I am getting an error that `this.state.renderData.filter is not a function`. I am new to ReactJS.

**Code**

```
    class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      Item: 5,
      skip: 0
    }

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  urlParams() {
    return `http://localhost:3001/meetups?filter[limit]=${(this.state.Item)}&&filter[skip]=${this.state.skip}`
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({skip: this.state.skip + 1})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.urlParams()}>Example link</a>
        <pre>{this.urlParams()}</pre>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change link</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.querySelector('div#my-example' ))
```

Comment: Are you sure that `nextProps.searchData` is an array?

Comment: Can you toss `console.log(this.state.renderData)` right before you try to filter it and tell it what it says it is?

Comment: @larz. It give an empty Array

Comment: @UjinT34 . Yes , it array

Comment: Well, `[].filter` most definitely is a function.  Maybe you're missing something else the error message is trying to tell you?

Comment: @larz. I am getting this error `this.state.renderData.filter is not a function` . I don't know where I have made mistake

Comment: do you have any tests at all? Your component has many functions with multiple conditions and state changes, and also your render function has a lot of stuff in it. As you may know, according to react component's lifecycle the render function is always going to be called first, so if there is anything inconsistent with your initial state or the props you are passing around your console is going to shout at you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your initial state of

```
this.state = {
  renderData:[],
  ...
}
```

is overwritten when `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, renderProps) {...}` is called.

Consider the following call to `connect(...)`:

```
connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getParties, searchData }
)(Organization)
```

The second argument to the `connect()` function - usually referred to as `mapDispatchToProps`, which is an object in your case - expects its attributes to be action creators (functions). The call to `connect(...)` will set your component's `searchData` prop to the value of the action creator that you import with `import { getParties, searchData } from "../../actions";`.

Because

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, renderProps) {
  ...
  this.setState({
    ...,
    renderData: nextProps.searchData
  });
  ...
}
```

is called before your component renders, the value of `this.state.renderData` won't be `[]`, but an action creator and thus `filter` is not a function on your action creator.